# How do I use collision_object.header.frame_id? Can I use it for frame transformations?

Tags: ros, collision-object, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to add collision objects to the world using a frame that is broadcast by a node. Setting

```
collision_object.header.frame_id = "task_frame"
```

results in the planner responding that

> Unable to transform from frame 'task_frame' to frame '/base_link'. Returning identity.

I tried setting my

```
collision_object.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

but no luck. I know task_frame exists, because I can run through tf_echo just fine. I can also manually transform poses, but the code will soon become really ugly as the list of objects increases.

Am I using collision_object.header wrong?

[frames.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14004971479421922.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166606/how-do-i-use-collision_object.header.frame_id?-can-i-use-it-for-frame-transformations?/) by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-19**:
Can you upload on image of the tf using `$ rosrun tf view_frames $ evince frames.pdf` ? And I know its working but could you add the output of `rosrun tf tf_echo /map /odom` ?

**Comment by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on 2014-05-19**:
I don't have /map or /odom transforms, are they required? I'm transforming directly from the base_link of the robot (which is stationary), to a particular configuration of the end_effector. I'll edit my question to include an image of the tf.

**Comment by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on 2014-05-19**:
Weird, it suddenly stared working, I didn't change anything. I suppose there might be some suboptimal way I've set up my transforms/timing/planning_scene somewhere.

**Comment by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on 2014-05-19**:
And now it is back where I started. I even added a wait for transform before setting my collision_object.header to prove to myself that the frame is coming through. Every node that I can think of can see "task_frame" except my planner. I'm out of ideas.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-19**:
It's probably a typo somewhere but when I look at your image, I don't see any task_frame, I see task_space...

**Comment by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on 2014-05-19**:
Yeah, it's a type in the question. But everything is spelled correctly in the code. I imagine it has to do with the timestamp, embedded in the collision_object, but I can't find a solution that works.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-20**:
Ok osrry it's the end of my knowledge. I have no idea why it does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that restarting the planner after the new transform has been published does the trick. I suppose it loads a list of transforms to subscribe to, and doesn't update that list after it has been started. Thanks for the help, it did at least clear up that I was on the right track :)

---

Originally posted by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) with karma: 157 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-21**:
Hey! Just realize by you saying it actually doesn't actualize the transformation loaded. I don't think it's a normal behavior of the system. Are you, by any chance doing something as describe here : http://answers.ros.org/question/39643/problem-with-roscore-subscription-and-publishing/ ?

**Comment by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on 2014-05-21**:
Yes, it looks like it is the same kind of problem. I can't tell if this is undesired behaviour from ROS or if I just need to make sure that things are running in the correct sequence. It is impossible to change the sequence in certain applications for me.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-05-21**:
Last attempt to understand : is your roscore launch in a independant terminal ? =)

**Comment by [paturdc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14791/paturdc/) on 2014-05-21**:
Yes, I have multiple terminals, and my subscriber is launched in a different terminal than my publisher (and the subscriber is launched before the publisher).